# Set the value for each option of an HTML drop down list to a PHP variable

Tags: php, html, sql

I want my dropdown list to show in the options the names from an sql table but the value to be the ID from the sql table. How do I achieve this?

```
<select name="Warehouse">
<?php


$servername = "127.0.0.1";
$username = "root";
$password = "12345";
$db_name = "Second";
$the_port = "3306";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$db_name,$the_port);

$conn->set_charset('utf8');

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    echo "err";
} 
// fetch ID,Name_of  from table
 $sql="SELECT ID,Name_of FROM WAREHOUSE;";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        $val=$row['ID']; 

        echo "<option value=".$val." >" . $row['Name_of'] . "</option>";

    }

?></select>
```

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: Accept anyones answer so it would be known to others

Comment: I answered already...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the error was in the sql query, in the SELECT I never got the ID.

Thanks anyway.

Comment: The echo is perfect, the problem was in the SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Your echo code needs some changes it should be like this

```
echo "<option value='".$val."' >" . $row['Name_of'] . "</option>";
                   ^^^      ^^^
```

and you need to change your query to

```
$sql="SELECT ID,Name_of FROM WAREHOUSE";
```

Answer (score 1):

change you query form

```
 $sql="SELECT Name_of FROM WAREHOUSE;";
```

to

```
$sql="SELECT ID,Name_of FROM WAREHOUSE;";
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
<option value="$val">$row['Name_of']</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
echo "<option value=".$row['ID']." >" . $row['Name_of'] . "</option>";
```